# Perform MD5 action before payment in DIBS

Tags: php, dibs

I am new in PHP....I need help on to trigger a function on DIBS HTML payment form for MD5 calculation

The PHP code to perform mds action for DIBS

```
$parameter_string= '';
$parameter_string.= 'merchant='. $yourMerchantID;
$parameter_string.= '&orderid='. $yourOrderID;
$parameter_string.= '&currency='. $yourCurrency;
$parameter_string.= '&amount='. $yourAmount;
$md5key= MD5($key2. MD5($key1. $parameter_string) );
```

Here the HTML code

```
 < form id="payment-form" 
   action="https://payment.architrade.com/paymentweb/start.action" 
   method="post" name="payform" onsubmit="return onPaymentFormSubmit();">

 < input name="lang" type="hidden" value="en" />

 < input name="currency" type="hidden" value="123" />

 < input name="merchant" type="hidden" value="123456" />

 < input type="hidden" name="md5key" value=""> 

 < input id="amount-text" name="amount-text" type="text" value="" />

 < input id="amount" name="amount" type="hidden" />

 < input name="orderid" type="text" value="" />

 < input name="accepturl" type="hidden" value="http://www.example.com/payment-accepted/"/>

 < input type="submit" value="Pay" />
```

Comment: kindly include the error(s) you got

Comment: sorry...no errors is yet now...bcz don't understand how to implement this function inside form

Comment: the value tag on input "md5key" is empty.. you need to change this

Comment: this value will be unique for every single transaction...the above php specific code to do this automatically